# superscript spacing, rule 18, delta, s

Tags: tex-core, superscripts

### background

I want to understand spacing rules for supersript.

Note: I ONLY care about horizontal spacing. The vertical spacing makes perfect sense. The horizontal spacing -- I don't know which constants to look up.

### what I have tried:

please see two images below

### what I am confused on:

1. how is delta defined ? Which part of the texbook rule 18 defines it?
2. according to rule 18, the value of s is '\scriptspace' -- okay, how do I compute the width of a \scriptspace ?

### related images

[image: appendix g illuminated section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\scriptspace` isn't computed it is just a length (latex sets it to 0.5pt)  but you can set it to anything else.

for delta see

> \rule 18f. Finally, let $\delta$ be zero unless it was set to a
>   nonzero value by Rules 13 or 17. \ (This is the amount of horizontal
>   displacement between subscript and superscript.)